# navbar doesn't show correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently teaching myself web based languages and I am a bit stuck on my bootstrap/html code. Currently I am running into some trouble with bootstrap. I am trying to make a navbar and I have copied code I found online and pasted on Atom and then ran the local site.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>testing</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <!-- Collapse button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
            class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>

      <!-- Collapsible content -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="\Users\sealc\.atom\Web Dev\testing\pagethree.html">page three</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\sealc\.atom\Web Dev\testing\pagetwo.html">Page two</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="C:\Users\sealc\.atom\Web Dev\testing\pagefour.html">Page four</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Links -->

      </div>
      <!-- Collapsible content -->

    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

it works when I fiddle with it on codeply, but when I try to run the local site I keep getting this:[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivAYl.png)

It is probably an easy fix, but I am no expert, I already tried using different links for bootstrap an I copied the template on their website, but nothing changed

Comment: You have included **Bootstrap 3.x** on header but the code you have belongs to **Bootstrap 4**. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on my environment the link might not work. I changed the link and it worked again. Here it is:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the conflict something  like:

How many `.JSFile` Version you are using?
If you have A `master page` i guess that is the cause. (Cause by the other pages)

To Resolve:
Try to comment some other .JS and run to check the cause.

May check also your .CSS using inspect element.

By Forcing the style you want or to By pass the old css, you can add in your style `!important` to the affected area.

Like for Example:

```
<style>
   .sampleclass{
     color: red !important
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Jacob Dubois I have check your code. Your code is perfect but bootstrap css has a problems. Please use this bootstrap latest version. For Example :=>   **https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css**